# Is there a way to stop an already executing command from completing in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

The command I want to cancel before completion is the repeat command, if a user does a command along the lines of `.stoprepeat`.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import asyncio
import string
import time
import random
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import os

class Botting(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Botting Cog is online and connected to Discord")

    @commands.command()
    async def repeat(self, ctx, times: int, *, content):
        """Repeats a message multiple times."""
        for i in range(times):
            await ctx.send(content)
            await asyncio.sleep(0.75)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Botting(client))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using an [`asyncio.Task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) to run a separately defined coroutine.
You'd have to assign the `Task` to an attribute of the cog and use that to cancel it in the other command.

If you anticipate the command being run multiple times simultaneously, you could store a list of `Task`s and cancel each one in the other command.

Comment: By any chance could you help me by providing an example for how I would implement that into my code? if not thanks for your answer :D

Comment: It would be similar to [the discord.py background task example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task.py), except you'd create and cancel the task in commands.